# IActiveScript profiling - view script source

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, iactivescript

I am playing with IE's JavaScript Chakra engine.

I have [downloaded example code from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/JavaScript-Runtime-Hosting-d3a13880) and I am trying to figure out how to get the function source when I have just function IDand script ID.

I start profiling my js script and from profiler (`IActiveScriptProfilerCallback2`) output I can see what functions are compiled, called...

For example callback for `FunctionCompiled` looks like this. I get function id and script id, even function name, but I can't figure out how to find function source code.

```
HRESULT Profiler::FunctionCompiled(PROFILER_TOKEN functionId, PROFILER_TOKEN scriptId, const wchar_t *pwszFunctionName, const wchar_t *pwszFunctionNameHint, IUnknown *pIDebugDocumentContext)
{
    fwprintf(stdout, L"Profiler::FunctionCompiled: 0x%lx, 0x%lx, %s, %s\n", scriptId, functionId, pwszFunctionName, pwszFunctionNameHint);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a non null pIDebugDocumentContext?

Comment: sometimes yes, sometimes no. But it seems that it is NULL only during initialization, so maybe I could use it. I am trying it now, but still must check EnumCodeContexts method better. It seems that somehow I might be able to find function source there. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it.. Here is my ugly ScriptCompiled function.

```
HRESULT Profiler::ScriptCompiled(PROFILER_TOKEN scriptId, PROFILER_SCRIPT_TYPE type, IUnknown *pIDebugDocumentContext)
{
    fwprintf(stdout, L"Profiler::ScriptCompiled: 0x%lx, %u\n", scriptId, type);

    if (pIDebugDocumentContext) {
        IDebugDocumentContext *debugDocumentContext = NULL;
        pIDebugDocumentContext->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugDocumentContext), (void**)&debugDocumentContext);

        IDebugDocument *debugDocument = NULL;
        debugDocumentContext->GetDocument(&debugDocument);

        IDebugDocumentText *debugDocumentText = NULL;
        debugDocument->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugDocumentText), (void**)&debugDocumentText);

        ULONG lines, chars;
        debugDocumentText->GetSize(&lines, &chars);

        printf("Lines: %d Chars: %d\n", lines, chars);

        chars++;
        WCHAR *text = (WCHAR*)malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * chars);
        ULONG charsRetrieved = 0;
        debugDocumentText->GetText(0, text, NULL, &charsRetrieved, chars);
        text[charsRetrieved] = L'\0';

        wprintf(L"%s\n", text);
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```